# Ajax with yii2 controller

Tags: ajax, post, yii2

When I click on my link , I would that when I click on the link i reload another div content and when I past the full link in the navigator It's not accessible.

```
<a  onclick="getConversation('id_div_2','<?= $id;?>','<?= $user1['id'];?>','admin/ajaxMessage','<?= Yii::$app->getUrlManager()->getBaseUrl();?>')"
            class="list-group-item">
```

I got the following error :

[image]

That's my controller script

```
public function actionIndex()
    {   

        if(isset($_POST['idCurrentUser'])){

            $idCurrentUser = $_POST['idCurrentUser'];
            $idUser = $_POST['idUser']; 

            $all_conversations = Yii::$app->db->createCommand(" SELECT * FROM message WHERE sender_id=".$idCurrentUser." OR receiver_id=".$idCurrentUser. " AND last_message=True" )->queryAll();

            $user1= Yii::$app->db->createCommand(" SELECT * FROM user WHERE id=".$idUser )->queryOne();

            $one_conversation = Yii::$app->db->createCommand(" SELECT * FROM message WHERE ( sender_id=".$idCurrentUser." AND receiver_id=".$idUser.") OR ( sender_id=".$idUser." AND receiver_id=".$idCurrentUser.")" )->queryAll();

            ?>
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <div class="media">
                    <a href="mail-compose.html" class="btn btn-danger pull-right rounded"><i class="fa fa-share"></i></a>
                    <a class="pull-left" href="#">
                        <img src="http://img.djavaui.com/?create=50x50,144966?f=ffffff" alt="Rebecca Cabean" class="img-circle"/>
                    </a>
                    <?php $contact1= Yii::$app->db->createCommand(" SELECT * FROM user WHERE id=".$idCurrentUser)->queryOne(); ?>
                    <?php $contact2 = Yii::$app->db->createCommand(" SELECT * FROM user WHERE id=".$idUser)->queryOne(); ?>
                    <?php $one_conversation1  = Yii::$app->db->createCommand(" SELECT * FROM message WHERE ( sender_id=".$idCurrentUser." AND receiver_id=".$idUser.") OR ( sender_id=".$idUser." AND receiver_id=".$idCurrentUser.")" )->queryOne();    ?>
                    <?php $msg1=  $one_conversation1;  ?>
                    <div class="media-body">
                    <?php if ($msg1['sender_id']==$idCurrentUser ) { ?><h4 class="media-heading"><?= $contact2['username']; ?> <small>(<?= $contact2['fonction']; ?>)</small></h4><?php }  ?>
                    <?php if ($msg1['receiver_id']==$idCurrentUser ) { ?><h4 class="media-heading"><?= $contact2['username']; ?> <small>(<?= $contact2['fonction']; ?>)</small></h4> <?php }  ?>
                        <small>Thursday 5th July 2014-via Intercom</small>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div><!-- /.panel-heading -->
            <div class="panel-body">
            <?php foreach ($one_conversation as  $key => $msg ) : ?>
                <p>
                      <?= $msg['text']   ?>
                </p>
                <hr/>
            <?php endforeach; ?>   
            </div><!-- /.panel-body -->

            <?php
        return false;
        }

    }
```

And my ajax function looks like

```
function getConversation(IDdiv,idCurrentUser,idUser,ctrl,url){

    var idCurrentUser = idCurrentUser;
    var idUser = idUser; 

    var dataForm = {idCurrentUser: idCurrentUser,idUser: idUser};
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url:''+url+'/index.php?r='+ctrl+'/index',
        data:dataForm,
        success: function (response) {
            document.getElementById(IDdiv).innerHTML=response;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: error 500 is a server side error .. you should debug eg: xdebug you  controller action   for locate where is the error ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem in `type= 'POST'`, you try to use onclick in `a` tag and so you should use `GET` method in type ajax like that:

```
function getConversation(IDdiv,idCurrentUser,idUser,ctrl,url){

var CurrentUser = idCurrentUser;
var User = idUser; 

$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url:''+url+'/index.php?r='+ctrl+'/index',
    data:'CurrentUser='+CurrentUser+'&User='+User,
    success: function (response) {
        document.getElementById(IDdiv).innerHTML=response;
    }
  });
}
```